# bash script create a loopback on failure (using dialog)

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script using dialog to prompt user with questions, etc. One of steps is running a command to generate some info. I have a if statement for it in case it fails, what i want to do is, in case it fails to give a user ability to re-run it. A bit lost on how to do it.

Script itself

```
#!/bin/bash

#Generating UID

UID_GREP=${UID_GREP=dialog}
$UID_GREP --title "Appliance Imaging Script" --clear \
    --yesno  "Begin Generate UID for Appliance:" 10 30
    case $? in 
    0)  
      #uid generate script
      /usr/share/bin/create >/tmp/appliance_run.log 2>&1
      ;;  
    1)  
      clear
      echo "exiting"
      exit;;
    255)
      clear
      echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
      exit;; 
      esac

 #if Generation of UID fails
   if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
      UID_FAIL=${UID_FAIL=dialog}
      $UID_FAIL --title "UID Genenration failed" --clear \
          --yesno "UID failed to genenerate, would you like to try again" 10 30
          case $? in
    0)  
       #loopback to $UID_GREP

      ;;  
    1)  
      clear
      echo "exiting"
      exit;;
    255)
      clear
      echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
      exit;;
      esac

 fi
```

So basically, where it's says "#loopback to $UID_GREP" i want it, if yes is selected to loop back to the UID_GREP dialog screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you reformat your code by indenting each line 4 spaces instead of using the `>` quote formatting character? It's a little hard to read.

Comment: Working on it now, hehe, sorry, didn't think it would come out so ugly... good to know about 4 spaces...

Comment: `x=${x=foo}` works but seems a bit clumsy.  I prefer `x=${x-foo}` or `: ${x=foo}` for this.  Also consider replacing the empty string, e.g., `: ${x:=foo}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you should do is create a "main function" for your application, basically a loop, that will control the application flow.
And then separate all the dialogs to separate functions. And also consider separating the actual operation to a separate function where suitable.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable that holds information whether we have generated the UID.
uid_generated=0
loop_count=0    

generate_uid() {
    loop_count=$(( $loop_count + 1 )) #This can be used to check how many times we have failed
    echo "generating UI, execution $loop_count" >> log.txt #For testing purposes
    /usr/share/bin/create >/tmp/appliance_run.log 2>&1

    # Check our result
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        uid_generated=1
    fi

}

initial_dialog() {
    UID_GREP=${UID_GREP=dialog}
    $UID_GREP --title "Appliance Imaging Script" --clear \
    --yesno  "Begin Generate UID for Appliance:" 10 30
    case $? in
    0)
        #uid generate script
        generate_uid
    ;;
    1)
        clear
        echo "exiting"
        exit
    ;;
    255)
        clear
        echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
        exit
    ;;
    esac
}

check_result() {
    #if Generation of UID fails
    if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
        UID_FAIL=${UID_FAIL=dialog}
        $UID_FAIL --title "UID Genenration failed" --clear \
        --yesno "UID failed to genenerate, would you like to try again" 10 30

        case $? in
        0)
            #loopback to $UID_GREP
            generate_uid
            ;;
        1)
            clear
            echo "exiting"
            exit
            ;;
        255)
            clear
            echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
            exit
            ;;
        esac
    fi
}

# First, show the initial dialog
initial_dialog

# Then we enter our application loop, this might not be exactly what you want, but idea is
# to have variables that control the execution states.
# So you could have eternal while here as well, and other variables define which screen
# should be shown at what time, but to show that this is correct, I do this
while [ $uid_generated -eq 0 ]
do
    generate_uid

    # Consider showing some other screen, or other information in this dialog
    # For example informing user that "we have failed once, and re-generating etc"
    check_result
done

echo "UID generation done" #This will end the program
```

This is just an example, but it works. You can check from log.txt that how many times you have executed the uid generation. I kept the format similar to yours, so that it looks familiar to you and you can see the difference, but you might want to have more external variables that control the application flow.

Note that you don't need to check the failure code anymore in check result, since error checking is done in the generate_uid function. That function is purely to inform user that it failed.. but again, I didn't modify it to keep your original content same.

But I recommend moving the application logic separate from UI logic.

Comment: Btw, i used a lot of this, the only problem is, loop_counter counts each loop twice because there are two entry with "generate_uid". But other then that, awesome, thank you for giving me right direction. :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't really check it too much for bugs, I just wanted to show some idea of one way how one could build a main loop for application. It's good programming manner to separate UI from the actual operating logic, and while with bash there are some limitations, you can still do it with variables or temporary files (my preference). If you're interested, you can read up more about from `model-view-controller`-pattern. But, glad if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Just put everything inside a `while` loop. If you successfully run `create`, use the
break command to leave the loop. The second `case` statement can be nested in the default clause of the first, and can simply fall through to let the loop repeat if the user chooses to try again.

```
while true; do
    #Generating UID

    UID_GREP=${UID_GREP=dialog}
    $UID_GREP --title "Appliance Imaging Script" --clear \
        --yesno  "Begin Generate UID for Appliance:" 10 30
    case $? in 
        0)  
          #uid generate script
          /usr/share/bin/create >/tmp/appliance_run.log 2>&1
          break
          ;;  
        1) clear; echo "exiting"; exit
           ;;
        255) clear; echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"; exit
           ;; 

        *)  # All other non-zero exit statuses
            UID_FAIL=${UID_FAIL=dialog}
            $UID_FAIL --title "UID Genenration failed" --clear \
                --yesno "UID failed to genenerate, would you like to try again" 10 30
            case $? in
              1) clear; echo "exiting"; exit
                 ;;
              255) clear; echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"; exit
                 ;;
            esac
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the format you needed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generating UID

while :; do
    UID_GREP=${UID_GREP=dialog}
    "$UID_GREP" --title "Appliance Imaging Script" --clear \
        --yesno  "Begin Generate UID for Appliance:" 10 30
    case $? in
    0)
        # uid generate script
        /usr/share/bin/create >/tmp/appliance_run.log 2>&1
        # if Generation of UID fails
        if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
            UID_FAIL=${UID_FAIL=dialog}
            "$UID_FAIL" --title "UID Genenration failed" --clear \
                --yesno "UID failed to genenerate, would you like to try again" 10 30
            case $? in
            0)
                continue 2
                ;;
            1)
                clear
                echo "exiting"
                exit
                ;;
            255)
                clear
                echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
                exit
                ;;
            *)
                # What do we do with other codes?
                ;;
            esac
        fi
        break
        ;;
    1)
        clear
        echo "exiting"
        exit
        ;;
    255)
        clear
        echo "ESC Pressed... Exiting"
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        # What do we do with other codes?
        ;;
    esac
done

# Continues here after success. All other failure or cancellations make the code exit.
```